# Mysql: How to merge multiple rows to return only one row

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table having multiple rows and i want to merge some of his rows to be in one row, if row columns different then return 'Mixed Value' else return the column value

Example:

[image: SQL Table]

I want the result to be like that if i select row with id 1 and 2

[image: Table Resutls]

and if i select row with id 1,2 and 3

[image: Table Resutls]

Thank's in advance

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... We cant reproduce data easy from images..

Comment: If you select row 1 and 2 why is product_sku in your result mixed_value when in the data the product-sku is the same?

Comment: Thank's for your reply, i modified the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `CASE WHEN`and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`to get what you want. It isn't clear if you want to group by `price_id` or by `service_id`, but I will assume so.

```
SELECT MIN(id) id, 
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT firstname) > 1 THEN 'MIXED_VALUE' ELSE MIN(firstname) END firstname,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT lastname) > 1 THEN 'MIXED_VALUE' ELSE MIN(lastname) END lastname,
price_id, service_id,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT product_sku) > 1 THEN 'MIXED_VALUE' ELSE MIN(product_sku) END product_sku
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY price_id, service_id
```

Comment: Why group by price_id, service_id? i want also to make the same thing on it

Answer (score 1):

You could try using group_concat(distinct() )

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(firstname) SEPARATOR ' ') ,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(lastname) SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table
```